# How to create a centralized callback for multiple ajax requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I would like to be able to send multiple ajax requests and merge all the responses in a single callback, how can i do that without mess with callbacks inside each request?

**Instead of a system like this**
-> send ajax1
    on ajax1 success
         -> send ajax2
               on ajax2 success process both answer and render a view

**I would like to be able to request ajax1 and ajax2**

```
call ajax1
call ajax2
```

## > when both are finished

```
process answer from both requests in a single function

callback (response_ajax1, response_ajax2 ) {
    // process information
}
```

Comment: This has been answered many, many times before, so why you're posting a duplicate and answering it yourself is beyond me. +1 for effort at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to jquery, since it's version 1.5 we can use Deferred objects for this.

## What's a deferred object?:

> [...] deferreds can be thought of as a way to represent asynchronous (not realtime)
>   operations which can take a long time to complete *(ajax requests are
>   one of thoose examples)*.

-

> Deferred objects are the asynchronous alternative to blocking functions and the
>   general idea is that rather than your application blocking while it
>   awaits some request to complete before returning a result.

-

> [...] a deferred object can instead be returned immediately.

As summary:

> Deferred objects provides a way to register multiple callbacks into self-managed
>   callback queues, invoke callback queues as appropriate, and relay the
>   success or failure state of any synchronous or asynchronous function..

To answer the question:
http://jsfiddle.net/mreis1/DCmrN/

```
function _ajax(id){ 
    return $.ajax({
        url: '/echo/json/',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {param1: id},
        complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
          //called when complete
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            //console.log(data)
          //called when successful

        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          //called when there is an error
        }


});


}

// merge response data from both ajax calls when they are done
$.when( _ajax(1), _ajax(2) ).done(function(a1, a2){
      console.log(a1, a2);
});
```

**DOCUMENTATION**

http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

**SIMILAR PROBLEMS**

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/using-when-to-deal-with-response-of-multiple-ajax-calls-deferred-objects

**ARTICLES TO EXPLORE**

http://www.tentonaxe.com/index.cfm/2011/9/22/Using-jQuerywhen-with-a-dynamic-number-of-objects

http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/

http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/examples/

Comment: Your wrapper function is completely unnecessary.

Comment: The wrapper function pretends to simplify the amount of code necessary to perform ajax calls. This wrapper can be greatly improved but the this examples pretends to show how it can be made. Examples at the end of the post pretend to complement the post it self. Thanks ;)